# issue with str.split() when trying to run the same function - Column not being 'erased'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple function that works fine, however when I am trying to run it again, I get an error. It's probably caused by str.split(), that I am using in one column of a dataframe (and then dataframe.explode). When I am trying to run the same code again, dataframe is loaded correctly, but this specific column is not - it has a values of previous run. This is simplified example of my code:

```
file_1 = pd.read_excel(example.xls)

def Validation_text():

    text = pd.DataFrame(file_1)
    text['Action_Type'] = text['Action_Type'].str.split(',')
    text = text.explode('Action_Type')
    print (text)
    ...
```

As Action_Type in original file, there can be one or more actions, and I am creating new line for each. Example:

```
Action Type in file:

New
Move
Move,Text
Delete
Move,Text,Update
```

When I run the code for the first time, printed output is correct and I can see that column 'Action Type' is correctly split:

```
[New]
[Move]
[Move, Text]
[Delete]
[Move, Text, Update]
```

But when I do that again 'Action_Type' column is empty - containing only NaN values and therefore program crashes (as there are other steps in program after this is being done). Everything else is fine, all other data are 'loaded' into dataframe again. I guess that those split Action_Type values are being stored somewhere in memory and not being loaded each time into dataframe. I tried to delete whole dataframe by using Del, even clean it with text = '', but nothing works.

Can anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: Create a minimal example [mcve] with an actual snippet of data that shows the issue. Just a snippet of data - we don't need a spreadsheet or the use of `pd.read_excel`. Just declare some example dataframe that shows the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by " when I do that again " you mean call the function ```Validation_text``` again or start the .py again?
You also have a lot of variables called ```text``` here and you should change this!

Comment: Panda50: Oh sorry yes, I call the same function again. all those variables were just an example. I cannot put other info as that might be confidential. The thing is, that when I skip the str.split() from the code everything works fine and I can call the same function how many times I want. However when I add str.split, then I have the issue described above.